# How to make jqgrid only works (show data) when we are searching?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jqgrid with toolbar search.
I want jqgrid to show empty grid when on load and show empty grid when i reset/clean toolbar search.
So i want dedicate this jqgrid just for searching.

How to make jqgrid only works (show data) when we are searching?

Thank you.

Best Regards,

Eka

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: I use 5.3.2 javascript version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use certain event to do this.

Initially your grid maybe will need to have datatype : local  and empty data parameter i.e

```
jqGrid({
    ...
    datatype: 'local',
    data : [],
    ...
});
```

When calling the toolbar filter use the two events - **beforeClear and beforeSearch** - see the [docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#toolbar-searching) for this purpose.

In **beforeSearch** event set datatype to 'json' and eventually the url, in **beforeClear** set the datatype again to local

Comment: Yes, I did it. You are awesome, Thank you Tony.